# Internet Explorer / Edge programmatically import saved passwords (Win10)

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-10, credentials, microsoft-edge

Is there an API to store passwords for websites in the Windows Web Credentials Vault?

I would like to import a database of credentials (from another program) into that storage without entering every password manually.

I was looking into CredWrite (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375187(v=vs.85).aspx) and vaultcmd, but the former does not seem to relate to the web-credentials and the latter will create the credentials, but the browsers will not use them (https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/5cb355eb-3671-48fc-b7ca-828fb865d87b/using-vaultcmd-to-create-web-credentials?forum=ieitprocurrentver&prof=required).

Comment: jrv over at https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/5cb355eb-3671-48fc-b7ca-828fb865d87b/using-vaultcmd-to-create-web-credentials?forum=ieitprocurrentver&prof=required keeps pointing out the guid D5B63C4E5625D84CA48DC755C737CBA6
without any explanation. Does anyone maybe get the point and hint me to an answer?

Comment: I asked over at https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/6f7dfffb-1566-4251-8c3d-a87058eab32b/programmatically-add-passwords-to-the-windows-web-credential-vault?forum=ieitprocurrentver as well